# Pandas row to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas and my goal is to write each row of the dataframe as a new json file.

I'm a bit stuck right now. My intuition was to iterate over the rows of the dataframe (using df.iterrows) and use json.dumps to dump the file but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pandas DataFrames have a to_json method that will do it for you:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

If you want each row in its own file you can iterate over the index (and use the index to help name them):

```
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i].to_json("row{}.json".format(i))
```

Comment: You're the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 40):

Looping over indices is very inefficient.

A faster technique:

`df['json'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)`

Comment: In your answer, the output is a series where as we want a json.

Comment: I'm guessing most people ending here want to transform each row into json, not necessarily export each row as an individual json, but indeed that is what the OP was asking so my answer is admittedly wrong.

Answer (score 23):

Extending the answer of @MrE, if you're looking to convert multiple columns from a single row into another column with the content in json format (and not separate json files as output) I've had speed issues while using:

```
df['json'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
```

I've achieved significant speed improvements on a dataset of 175K records and 5 columns using this line of code:

```
df['json'] = df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True).splitlines()
```

Speed went from >1 min to 350 ms.

Answer (score 3):

Using apply, this can be done as

```
def writejson(row):
  with open(row["filename"]+'.json', "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(row["json"], outfile, indent=2)

in_df.apply(writejson, axis=1)
```

Assuming the dataframe has a column named "filename" with filename for each json row.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

transform a dataframe to json per record, one json per line. then simply split the lines

`list_of_jsons = df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True).splitlines()`