# Convert .csv to .jsonl python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, data-conversion

I have a .csv file which I would like to convert into a .jsonl file.

I found the Pandas `to_json` method:

```
df = pd.read_csv('DIRECTORY/texts1.csv', sep=';')
df.to_json ('DIRECTORY/texts1.json')
```

However, I am not aware of a function to turn it into a .jsonl format. How can I do this?

Comment: https://jsonlines.org/

Comment: As I said, `a lot of attempts to hijack a common practice`. Just append the JSON strings at the end of the file you want. That;s the whole point. You only need to read to the next newline to read a JSON document instead of reading the entire file.

Comment: In fact, `ndjson.org` appeared before `jsonlines.org` and contained the same text as the historical `json.org` site, without having *any* relation to either Douglas Crockford or ECMA

Comment: The whole point of storing a JSON document per line is that you *don't* have to read either the document or the data in memory. It's the same benefit CSV has. You can read the CSV file line-by-line, generate a JSON string from each line, and just append it to the target file. This way you could handle eg a 10GB without using any more data than necessary to process and serialize a single line.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64700027/134204) you can see that `to_json` can write each row in a separate row if you use `orient='records', lines=True`. From [to_json docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html): `If ‘orient’ is ‘records’ write out line delimited json format. Will throw ValueError if incorrect ‘orient’ since others are not list like.`

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a bit late, but I wrote a silly module called [csv-jsonl](https://pypi.org/project/csv-jsonl/) that may help with this sort of thing.

```py
>>> from csv_jsonl import JSONLinesDictWriter
>>> l = [{"foo": "bar", "bat": 1}, {"foo": "bar", "bat": 2}]
>>> with open("foo.jsonl", "w", encoding="utf-8") as _fh:
...     writer = JSONLinesDictWriter(_fh)
...     writer.writerows(l)
...
```

It extends the native `csv` module, so it's mostly familiar. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this result is compliant with "jsonl" syntax, but it's a hack that might get towards a relevant outcome.

The primary trick is to treat each line of the input file as a separate JSON file upon export, then read that JSON back in from disk and treat as distinct jsonl lines.

I'm starting from a CSV that contains

```
hello, from, this, file
another, amazing, line, csv
last, line, of, file
```

The snippet below builds on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051134/pandas-row-to-json/36051289).

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("myfile.csv", header=None)

file_to_write = ""
for index in df.index:
    df.loc[index].to_json("row{}.json".format(index))
    with open("row{}.json".format(index)) as file_handle:
        file_content = file_handle.read()
        file_to_write += file_content + "\n"
        
with open("result.jsonl","w") as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(file_to_write)
```

The resulting .jsonl file contains

```
{"0":"hello","1":" from","2":" this","3":" file"}
{"0":"another","1":" amazing","2":" line","3":" csv"}
{"0":"last","1":" line","2":" of","3":" file"}
```

If the row indices are not desired, those could be removed from the .to_json() line of the Python snippet above.